# É possível criar um evento do facebook através da Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-sdk

Tentei pesquisar em alguns lugares, mas sem sucesso ou o conteúdo é antigo.

Eis a pergunta:
Estou desenvolvendo um app e gostaria de saber se é possível criar um evento do facebook através da Graph API ou do Android SDK?

Comment: De acordo com a documentação do `Facebaook`, você não pode criar eventos.

Comment: @RafaelAugusto link ou isso nunca foi dito.

Comment: Acabei tendo um tempo maior, e peguei a documentação para ler.
link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/event/
@Renan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é possível de acordo com a documentação do Facebook:

```
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/event/
```